# chipmunks burrowing under above ground pool

Tags: pool

Chipmunks have burrowed under above ground pool causing liner to indent over their burrow.  How do I stop further erosion under liner?

Comment: Be sure to install the compacted gravel with compacted sand base recommended when you end up having to drain to repair for this.

Comment: Ah, so now I know why the gravel base is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the chipmunks. The liner stretches to drop into depression. If it stretches too much ,it will have a small leak. This mobilizes the soil to sink further; not leading to a happy ending ( been there, done that). I think the only practical repair is a new liner and fill any low spots before installing it.